# php pchart 2.0 x-axis abscissa position (bottom rather than top)

Tags: php, axis, pchart

Using pchart 2 I am looking for a reliable (hopefully built in) way to move the abscissa (x-axis) of a bar chart to the bottom of the chart rather than the top.

[image: As standard the x-axis renders at the top]

So considering the above image, I would like to move the 'Hits' axis to the bottom of the chart.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

`$MyData->setAxisPosition(0,AXIS_POSITION_BOTTOM);`

indeed, something like setAbscissaPosition would be easier.